# How to collapse or expand data in details section of crystal report 2011?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Is it possible to collapse or expand data in details section of crystal report 2011?

I tried to use Hide (Drill-down OK) but it doesn't bring + or - signs of to expand or collapse, it works like subreport.

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Detail section prints for every record, what is your exact requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To drill down to the details of a group, on the print preview you double-click any data fields you've placed in the group header or footer, the hidden details section then appear.